# Make a function argument optional if the inferred type is an empty object

Tags: typescript

How can I make a functions argument required if the inferred type exists with keys, and optional if it does not exist or it is an empty object?

I've tried doing it with conditionals and with overloads but havent figure it out yet.

```
const MyFunc = <T extends {}>(vars?: T): void => {
  // ...
}

// Should be allowed
MyFunc()

// Should be allowed
MyFunc<{}>()

// Should not be allowed - the argument should be required
MyFunc<{ a: string }>()
```

I've tried overloads and conditional types checking `keyof T extends never ? ...` but Im stumped. Is this even possible with current TypeScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL2zZw) meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz ah yes brilliant thanks! I'll mark it as correct if you add an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you apparently want `MyFunc` to always be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function with exactly one type parameter `T` corresponding to the type of the `vars` argument, the only place we can make this change is to the parameter types of your call signature.  If you relaxed that restriction, then [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) and other approaches would probably give you similar effects, but that would be a different question.

My suggested solution looks like

```
const MyFunc = <T extends {}>(
   ...args: {} extends T ? [vars?: T] : [vars: T]
): void => { }
```

where instead of a single `vars` parameter, we have an `args` [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) that depends [conditionally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) on whether an empty object type is assignable to `T`.  If so, then the tuple has a single [optional element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) of type `T` and therefore `vars` is optional.  If not, then the tuple has a single required element and therefore `vars` is required.

Let's test it out:

```
MyFunc(); // okay
MyFunc<{}>(); // okay
MyFunc<{ a: string }>(); // error!
MyFunc<{ a?: string }>(); // okay
```

Looks good.  Note that since `{}` is a valid value for `{a?: string}`, then `MyFunc<{a?: string}>()` is allowed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwGIFczBgXhgHgCowCmAHlIWACYQwDeAvgHwAUAdGwIYBOA5hAFy06RUuSowCAfhgBtAG5cIEgXgC6MAXIXKVASgGyQASwpYGtAFAwYAemsw2Lc3XOJU6JjoDcNuyADW7AguyGjAOPTMXj4w-oHBbmE0MOwC0JyGYNwwjB7etkScnCCcAITxoeHJSjBpGVk5UfmxQUA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, spot on!

Comment: As an alternative to `{} extends T` you could also use `keyof T extends undefined`.